# Databases and DVCS

Tags: database, dvcs

I've recently asked a question about how suitable a DVCS is for the corporate environment, and that has sparked another question for me.

One of the plus sides to a DVCS seems to be that you can easily branch and try out new things. My problem starts when I begin to think about database changes. I've always found it tricky to get a DB into a VCS and it just sounds like it's going to be even harder with a DVCS.

So, whats the best way to work with databases and a DVCS?

**EDIT:** I've started looking into Migrator.NET. What do people think of projects like this for easily moving between versions specificaly with experimental branches in your DVCS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to deal with this issue is to work with DB Schemas, not the databases themselves.  In this case, each developer would have their own database to develop against.

Here are some of the options available:

- **Migrations** framework within Ruby on Rails.
- **South** for Django, in addition to the schema being defined in the model classes themselves.
- **Visual Studio 2008 Team System Database Edition** for .NET: You define the schema and the tool can do a diff on schema and data to generate scripts to go between different versions of the database.

These may give you some inspiration on how to deal with putting a database in version control.  Another benefit that comes when you deal schemas is that you can more readily implement TDD and Continuous Integration (CI).  Your TDD/CI environment would be able to build up a new version of the database and then run tests against the newly generated environment.

Answer (score 1):

Version all the scripts you're using to manage your database. If you need to have "in-development" changes to a DB, make them on your personal DB until such time as you "publish" your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Database version control is always the most difficult thing in a multi-developer environment.

Typically each user will have their own DB which is a chimera of some but not all of the DB changes.  When they make changes, they'll need to commit their change scripts.  This gets really awkward.  The core problems seem to stem from database changes affecting many aspects of the system and multiple table changes being dependent on each other - and how to migrate to the new schema from the old schema.  Migrating data to a new schema is typically non-trivial.  Often you want to default a column when data is copied to the new schema, but NOT default a column in general for INSERT, say.  These are typically already difficult in production deployment issues and having to manage the database during development when the database design could be in major flux in the same way as a major deployment is a lot more work than you usually need to be doing in development.  Time that could be better spent ensuring that your database is well-designed - constraints, foregin keys, etc.

Because the developers are more likely to step on each other with database changes, we always had a database chokepoint - the developers all developed against the SAME development database and made their changes "live".  Then the dev database was version controlled independently.  This is not really easy when people are offsite or whatever.  Another alternative is to have designated database developers who coordinate changes several developers need to the same table - that doesn't need to be their entire job, but gives you better DB design consistency.  Or you can coordinate database revisions so that people become more aware of the DB revs other people are doing and time their changes to wait until a DB rev is available from another developer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to not put database into VCS in binary form. Period.

If you have text representation of your database and you have special merge tool to resolve conflicts when your database will be changed in different branches -- then you can start thinking about versioning databases. Otherwise it will be constant pain in the ass.